# Problem passing parameters in Retrofit api using POST method

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit2

I want to get notifications from a server using API. I'm using Retrofit2 to work with API.

The problem is when I'm passing parameter in POST method I'm getting "IllegalArgumentException URL does not contain the parameter."

The parameter is correct and working in iOS. I want to implement in android.

Below is the result when debugging the app.

```
      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL 
      "notification/newnotification" does not contain "{userid}". (parameter #1)
```

I've tried changing parameters and asked the API developer too. He says parameter is correct.

This is code for API Interface:

```
public interface API{
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("notification/newnotification")
    Call<ResponseBody> getUserNotification(
        @Path("userid") int userid
    );
 }
```

RetrofitClient.java

```
public class RetrofitClient {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://danceglobe.co/dance/api/";
private static RetrofitClient mInstance;
private Retrofit retrofit;

private RetrofitClient(){
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance(){
    if(mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public API getApi(){
    return retrofit.create(API.class);
}


}
```

Calling Function from MainActivity

```
    private void getNotification(String currentUserId) {
    Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getUserNotification(Integer.parseInt(currentUserId));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response.message(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            try {
                String s = response.body().string();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

I want it to respond to some data.

Please help me. I got stuck into this from past 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by making some changes in API interface.
Below is new Code for API interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("notification/newnotification")
Call<ResponseBody> getUserNotification(
        @Field("userid") String userid   // changed line 
);
```

Comment: you changed userid in the api from pathparam to queryparam?

Comment: i've changed it to Field("userid") String userid from Path("userid") String userid

Comment: read: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Field.html
you changed `userid` from being a pathvariable (/{userid} in the url ) to a requestbody of (userid={userid} in the body of your request) if this is how the API works, your question isn't very well verbalized.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL 
  "notification/newnotification" does not contain "{userid}". (parameter #1)
```

means you should add the userId to the path like

```
public interface API {
    @POST("notification/newnotification/{userid}")
    Call<ResponseBody> getUserNotification(
        @Path("userid") int userid
    );
}
```

`@Path("userid")` maps the variable to the placeholder `{userid}`, that was missing.

Comment: thanks for help. i got it working by changing Path to Field

Comment: this way it does not worked. it shows Form-encoded method must contain at least one @Field.